# Can we find an inner product under this condition

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $(W,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_W)$ be an inner product space and let $V$ be a linear subspace of $W$. Let $f: V \rightarrow W$ be an injective linear map.

If we fix $v' \in V$ and $w' \in W'$, does there exists an inner product on $V$ such that

$$\langle v',v\rangle_V = \langle w',f(v)\rangle_W, \qquad \forall v \in V  \quad?$$

EDIT: After the comment of aschepler, this doesn't work if $\langle w',f(v')\rangle\leq 0$.

So let's add the assumption that $\langle w',f(v')\rangle \geq 0$.

Comment: Not possible if it happens that $\langle w', f(v') \rangle_W \leq 0$.

Comment: Good point @aschelper, thank you!

Comment: is that supposed to be $w' \in W$? Or if not, how is $w'$ related to $w$? Also, aschepler's problem was for $\le 0$. Just requiring $\ne 0$ is not enough to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Paul Sinclair, I'm using $ w$ and $w'$ for the same thing my bad. I'll fix that.